# Possible to put <script> to a AngularComponent?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

in the component.ts theres a list where you relate url's an styleUrl's to the component:

```
okkook

@Component({

  selector: 'home',

  templateUrl: './home.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']

})
```

how can i relate a javascript file that i have already made? **how can i relate a** **Javascript Template?**

it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to use Google Analytics on your component,

first you declare the javascript file on your `index.html`

```
...
 <script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
...
```

Then on your component (or any .ts file) you could access the function inside that javascript file like this:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
declare const ga: any;

@Component({...})
export class Component{
   constructor(){
      ga('create', "GA_ID", 'auto');
   }
 }
```